# What do you call a _________ of cloth?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

Something that refers to a collection of folded up cloth you'd buy at a store. An official term? I'm blanking.

Comment: Have you looked this up on fabric websites? What did you find?

Comment: Isn't cloth normally bought by the yard or the metre?

Comment: Depending on how much, you might be thinking of a [bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(fabric)).

Comment: Do you really mean a collection? Like several different patterns of fabric, each cut to a standard size and sold together? In that case I think you're probably thinking of a **fat quarter *bundle*** (occasionally other sizes than fat quarters are also sold in bundles, but in the US that's by far the most common).

Comment: Stash (your whole collection of fabric/cloth), stack (generic group of different fabrics that you can literally stack), bundle (specific to bundles of fat quarters etc... for quilting, all the pieces in a bundle should be the same size).

Answer (score 50):

***[Bolt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/bolt):***

> a length or roll of cloth or wallpaper

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> [A bolt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(fabric)) is a unit of measurement used as an industry standard for a variety of materials from wood to canvas, typically materials stored in a roll. Length will vary according to the type of material measured.[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/bolt) The length is usually either 40 or 100 yards, but varies depending on the fabric being referred to.

(Wikipedia)

[image] bolts of cloth

[image]

from Wikipedia

The usage of ***[bolt](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bolt)*** referring to cloth is  very old, it dates back to the 15th century:

> Applied since Middle English to other short metal rods (especially those with knobbed ends).  ***A bolt of canvas (c. 1400) was so called for its shape.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: As someone who has bought cloth by the yard off the bolt on several occasion in the US, I can say that at least in my area, it's still called a bolt of cloth even when it's cut off the proper bolt. Generally it's taken off the roll and folded while it is being measured, prior to being cut off the roll for sale, and then it may be further folded in half to put in a shopping bag if it is flexible enough.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call a word from the 15th century "very" old.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you're referring to a bundle of different cloths that are sold for quilting. If so, then you're usually talking about *fat quarters* (18x22 inches) or *cake layers* (9" squares). There are even smaller charm squares (about 5") which are sold in bundles, but these are not always folded.

https://www.nationalquilterscircle.com/article/glossary-of-quilting-terms/

Comment: Fat quarters is what first came to my mind

Comment: Those rather describe the sizes rather than being a collection though. It's perfectly possible to buy one fat quarter if that's all you need.

Answer (score 4):

even possibly a **remnant**

cloth left after the rest has been sold or used

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/amounts-and-pieces-of-cloth

Answer (score 4):

**Swatch** (noun), from Google:

> a small sample of fabric intended to demonstrate the look of a larger piece.
>
> - a collection of fabric samples, especially in the form of a book.

I suggest this because of your use of the word "collection" in your question.

While `bolt` is the common name for the standard unit of cloth, it typically only holds a single color/pattern. If you are looking for the collection of patterns/fabrics for sampling purposes, `swatch` might fit best.

Comment: This is the best answer in my mind. Merriam's description matches well.

Answer (score 1):

[**ream**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ream) (noun)

> 2 : a great amount —usually used in plural

---

Although typically used to described paper, one could say:

> I am going to buy a **ream** of cloth.

or

> The store has many **reams** of cloth to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

A *pile* of cloth **maybe**. A pile could be a collection of stacked or unstacked clothes.